# Browser-back: filter settings get lost with my custom ReportViewer and web config

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, web-config, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

**Problem**
Using SSRS its default Report.aspx & webconfig, state1 & state2 (below) are equal.
My custom report.aspx with modifications to webconfig, state1 & state2 below are not equal.

**Probable cause**
Session information might not be stored, due to changing webconfig options..?
This becomes visible when I browse through reports, and then use the browser-back button.

*The specific scenario:*

1. Open report (has parameters/filters, e.g. year: 2012)
2. Change default filter values, e.g. set year to 2011 (+submit) [ = state1 ]
3. Go to a drillthrough report
4. Go back (year is set to 2012 again) [ = state2 ]

With the default SSRS report.aspx, going back (step 4) is 2012 as expected. However, with my custom webconfig+ReportViewer aspx, the filters are different than before (2011 again).

My changes to web.config to bypass a previously encountered error:

> The type Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.WebControlConnection, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 does not implement IReportServerConnection

The web.config now has:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="ReportViewerServerConnection" value="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.WebControlConnection, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <add key="ReportViewerTemporaryStorage" value="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportViewerTemporaryStorage, ReportingServicesWebUserInterface, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <clear/><!-- added -->
</appSettings>
```

To bypass the error:

> In remote mode, the Report Viewer control requires session state be enabled or Report Server connection information specified in the config file.

I've changed:

```xml
<httpModules>
    <clear />
    <add name="Session"  type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/><!-- added -->
    ...
    ...
</httpModules>
```

I'd be pleased to receiving your thoughts and/or suggestions/solutions.

**Update:**
Additional screenshots to the previous mentioned steps:

Step 1  ( = Step 4 custom )
[image: parameter settings at step 1]

Step 2  ( = Step 4 default, desired )
[image: parameter settings at step 2]

Step 4: going back with the default ssrs gives me Step 2 (as desired), with my custom gives me Step 1. I would like to achieve getting back at Step 2 also with my custom page.

**Update**
*Investigation with WebkitInspector*

In ssrs default aspx, going back in the browser (desired functionality):

Initially the filters are also in default state, but the server writes additional JS on the page, which initiates the update of the filters to previous settings. The point is that I dont know how to "automatically" write these additional JS (I think it is session/history related, in stead of programmatically storing & checking for history).

Further, I have been suggested to:

1. use dev toolbars or fiddler/wireshark for investigating session parameters.
2. querying the ReportServerTempDb

I will try #1, I'm really not sure where to begin concerning #2 though.

**Update:**
Appearently in IE only, it has some BrowserNavigationCorrector.js.
When you render a page, first the initialize is executed, which does a `setTimeout('doInitialize',0)`. After that - before the doInitialize will be executed -, the page writes/renders JS: `add_init(*NavigationCorrectioncode*);`
On doInit, the NavigationCorrector checks the PageState (in `OnAppLoad()`), which does NOT have the value 'Loaded' yet.
Then everything else happens, and the pagestate will get the value Loaded.

Then, when you go to a subreport and hit back, the page has in memory the state 'Loaded'. So when the NavigationCorrector executes its code, and the pagestate IS Loaded, it triggers a TriggerPostBack-script. This in turn, does a callback which updates the parametervalues.

Using WebForms.dll v11, the BrowserNavigationCorrector.js doesn't exist. Also, using Chrome, it also isn't included in neither SSRS native or using the dll.

Basically I can try to include that file manually, or, I'm currently trying to download VS2013 which hopefully has an improved version of the dll, maybe v12..?

Comment: I am trying to figure out why this is such a problem. Is the issue worth your time investigating?

Comment: Definately, I'd appreciate it a lot. As a sidenote, the changes in webconfig interferes with other pages, which has as a result that the default and my report.aspx cannot coexist.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem / your expectations a bit? When you hit the browser "Back" button do you expect the parameters to reset to (a) their defaults or (b) the value you had set for them when you left the page?

Comment: I updated the last line (from update 1), i.e. (b) from your comment ^ Then I added another update

Answer (score 0):

I think it appeared to be a bug in the DLL..
Tried to make a ticket once but it stranded somewhere along the process.. It may have been fixed in newer versions.